# Torque in a 3-phase delta connected induction motor

Tags: induction-motor, electrical

I know the equation for torque is

```
        T=[m*(N2/N1)^2/2*pi*Ns]*[s*E1^2*R2/R2^2+(s*X2)^2]
```

N2/N1 is the effecting rotor-stator turns ratio. I have it written like 0.90:1.

How would I write it as N2/N1? Would it be 1/0.90?

Comment: 0.90/1  = 0.90 if you put that in do you get a useful result?

Comment: My induction motor was 3 phase, and the torque value I got was 0.6Nm. I'm not sure if it sounds about right or not.

Comment: If I did it as 1/0.90=1.1 recurring, then I get an end value of torque=0.95Nm?

Comment: Which one sounds about right? Would be grateful if anyone could explain why which one is right?

Comment: Nothing "sound right" in this question. I would say that if the rotor-stator turns ratio is given as 0.90:1 that is 0.9 rotor turns for 1 stator turn and N2.N1 = 0.9/1. In most motor problems, the equivalent circuit is first simplified by adjusting the  X2 and R2 values for N1 = N2. I can not determine how that torque equation was derived.

Comment: I used the equation from this book 'Electrical and Electronic Principles and Technology, 5th Ed' by John Bird, Section 3, 3-phase Induction Motors, Torque Equation for Induction Motor, Page 398.

Comment: I looked up an example of the equation and they just used 0.85 from 0.85:1.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I write it as N2/N1? Would it be 1/0.90?

\$0.90:1\$ as a ratio is the equivalent of \$ \frac{0.9}{1} = 0.9 \$.

> [...] the torque value I got was 0.6Nm. I'm not sure if it sounds about right or not.

A torque of 0.6 Nm could be a correct answer as I have no idea what you have for parameters. You might want to edit your question to include the values you are using. Additionally, you could include your attempted calculation.

Consider the following chart for reference:

[image: Speed vs Torque and Power]
[1. Electric Motors - Power and Torque vs Speed](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/electrical-motors-hp-torque-rpm-d_1503.html)